# Sum of numbers from 0 to 2999999 in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am a Beginner here. I want to make comparison of runTime between the sequential and parallel (multithreading) summation of numbers from 0 to 2999999 in Java. I want to make sure myself that parallel sum is faster than sequential. I made a small program in Eclipse. However, I could not properly extract the results from threads and/or put them into the ArrayList to further sum them to have totalSum. My codes are attached. Please, help? Thank you in advance!

Here is the main class:

```
public class threading_sum {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Sequential summation:
    double sum_seq = 0;
    long beginTime_seq = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2999999; i++) {            
        sum_seq += i;
    }   
    long endTime_seq = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Sequential sum took "+(endTime_seq-beginTime_seq)+" ms. Sum is "+sum_seq);  

    //Parallel summation with 3 threads:
    long beginTime_par = System.currentTimeMillis();
    runnable R1 = new runnable(0, 999999, "Thread-1");
    R1.start();

    runnable R2 = new runnable(1000000, 1999999, "Thread-2");
    R2.start();

    runnable R3 = new runnable(2000000, 2999999, "Thread-3");
    R3.start();

    //Sum of results from all threads:
    System.out.println(runnable.arr);
    int totalSum = 0;
    for (double i : runnable.arr) {
        totalSum += i;
    }       
    long endTime_par = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Parallel sum took "+(endTime_par-beginTime_par)+" ms. Sum is "+totalSum);
}
}
```

Here is the runnable class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class runnable implements Runnable {

private Thread t;
private int begin;
private int end;
private String threadName;

public runnable(int b, int e, String T_name) {
    begin = b;
    end = e;
    threadName = T_name;
}

static ArrayList<Double> arr = new ArrayList<Double>();

public void run() {
    double sum =0;
    for (int i = begin; i <= end; i++) {            
        sum += i;
    }
    arr.add(sum);
}
public void start() {
    if (t == null) {
        t = new Thread(this, threadName);
        t.start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: *I want to make sure myself that parallel sum is faster than sequential* - There is no guarantee that using multiple threads will make it faster. Why do you plan on doing this *explicitly*?

Comment: Yes I know that there is no guarantee. But this project is for one of my classes. And the requirement from a techer was that the parallel program should work faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the *correct* result you should modify your program to join the spawned threads (wait till their finish):

```
// in runnable class:
public void join() throws InterruptedException {
    t.join();
}

// in main:
R1.join();
R2.join();
R3.join();

// Sum of results from all threads:
System.out.println(runnable.arr);
double totalSum = 0; // also use double instead of int here
for (double i : runnable.arr) {
    totalSum += i;
}
long endTime_par = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

To get the *faster* result you should remember that starting a new thread is a complex operation which introduces quite big overhead. In contrast summing 3000000 int numbers is very fast. So you unlikely to get any benefit in such a simple test. Commonly the pre-created set of threads is used (called "thread pool") and these threads are just waiting for the new tasks to execute. Such thread pools are managed by executors (see [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)). Also note that measuring the time is not that easy. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java8

```
long sumLongStream(LongStream stream) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    long sum= stream.sum();
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    return end - start;
}

@Test
public void testSumLong() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        long sequential = sumLongStream(LongStream.range(0, 3000000));
        long parallel = sumLongStream(LongStream.range(0, 3000000).parallel());
        System.out.printf("sequential: %dns parallel: %dns%n", sequential, parallel);
    }
}
```

results:

```
sequential: 74134923ns parallel: 69891446ns
sequential: 3471362ns parallel: 1580152ns
sequential: 2865433ns parallel: 1611337ns
sequential: 2820038ns parallel: 1442387ns
sequential: 3113330ns parallel: 1207121ns
sequential: 1982790ns parallel: 1070540ns
sequential: 2370821ns parallel: 1070146ns
sequential: 2210950ns parallel: 1094619ns
sequential: 3575573ns parallel: 1481072ns
sequential: 1979237ns parallel: 1087120ns
```

Answer (score 0):

Program to sum numbers 0-2999999, and time it:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3000000; i++)
    sum += i;
long end = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(sum + " in " + (end - start) + "ns");
```

*Output (old Core 2 Duo processor)*

```
4499998500000 in 5869508ns
```

Or less that 6 milliseconds. It is so fast that simply starting up multiple threads and merging the results will take longer.

And that's without warming up JIT. So I ran to 10 times:

```
4499998500000 in 5633141ns
4499998500000 in 7538587ns
4499998500000 in 1558147ns
4499998500000 in 1460444ns
4499998500000 in 1399859ns
4499998500000 in 1652866ns
4499998500000 in 1796222ns
4499998500000 in 1796222ns
4499998500000 in 1795795ns
4499998500000 in 1796222ns
```

Now less than 2 milliseconds.